# How to create a stop loss at the value of the EMA when we enter a trade?

Tags: pine-script

How can I code a stop loss to be placed at the value of the EMA at the point of entry, and then set a take profit at a value based on risk to reward? Currently, my code causes the stop loss to activate when the price goes below the EMA at any point, even if it's higher than the entry price.

Answer (score 0):

In v5, you can do this :

```
RiskReward = 2
if myconditionforlong
    strategy.entry("MyLong", strategy.long) // to enter the trade
    // stop loss to be placed at the value of the ema 
    stoploss = ta.ema(close, 20)
    strategy.exit("StopLoss", from_entry="MyLong", stop=stoploss)
    // take profit at the value of risk reward
    takeprofit = close + (close-stoploss)*RiskReward
    strategy.exit("StopLoss", from_entry="MyLong", limit=takeprofit)
```